# string.indexOf() always returns a non-zero value

Tags: arduino-uno, string, eeprom

I am developing a hardware project which contains a facility to change the stored password by any user, if he/she knows the current password.The new password is stored in arduino eeprom. In the main screen, if the user enters the current password, door is unlocked from inside. . The issue faced here is that the point where current password is entered by user, it works fine, but **I want to check that '#' is not entered by user in the new password which is not performed properly.**

Because in the main screen, when user presses '#' key, change password function is called up, where user is asked to enter current password.

Here is the screenshot of the circuit prepared from fritzing.
[image]

The code snippet for entering new password is as under.

```
lcd.clear();
lcd.print("New Passkey:");
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
while (j < 4)
{
  char key = keypad4x4.getKey();

  if (key)
  {
    new_password[j++] = key;
    lcd.print(key);
    tone(buzzer, 1000, 50);

    if (j == 4)
    {
      lcd.print("4 reached");
      delay(1000);
      new_password[5] = '\0';
      String str = String(new_password);
      if (str.indexOf('#'))    /** this condition comes out to be true always i.e. always returns a non-zero value**/
      {
        tone(buzzer, 200, 700);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Invalid Entry");  /** It is printed everytime on lcd**/
        delay(2000);
        key = 0;
        changePass();
        break;
      }
      else  /** this block is not entered, so new password is not saved in EEPROM **/
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
          EEPROM.write(i, new_password[i]);
        }
        lcd.print(" Done......");
        delay(1000);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

`new_password[5]` is used to store new password entered by user.

Now, I am using a string variable to store this new password.

I am using  `string.indexof()` function to identify whether this new password contains a '#' character anywhere in it.But it seems that when I put this in an if block in code, it becomes true everytime.I have added comments at respective positions to highlight the problem faced by me. I have tested this code in Proteus simulator, and actual project too.

So, my issue is this one, **even if correct password is entered by user,without '#', then also, string.indexOf('#') condition becomes true(returns a non-zero value everytime) and thus even valid password is not saved in EEPROM**. 
I guess I was able to explain my query accurately, please go through the code, and tell me where I am wrong, because I have gone through it many times and could not find the exact issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check the reference? https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/indexof/

Comment: should be `if (str.indexOf('#')+1)`

Comment: Yes, I have checked the reference before using indexOf() in my code, but the `+1` thing you mentioned in your comment,I didn't quite understand it. What does it do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `indexOf` returns the position of the character in the string, or *-1 if it's not found*.

In C `0` is `false` and *everything else is true*. That includes `-1`.

However, your usage if String here to just check for one character is incredibly wasteful and should be avoided. Instead, use `strchr`:

```
if (strchr(new_password, '#') != NULL) {
    ... contains # ...
}
```

Comment: It really worked....@Majenko✌